# How to properly configure hp m1212nf on debian 12?

Tags: linux, debian, printing, printer, cups

I have installed hplip and cups on my debian 12, Cups sees my printer, but when I try to print test page CUPS says:
stopped
"Filter failed"

Printer displayed "used supply in use", but it's ok for this printer, chip doesn't need to be swapped to the new one.

Printer successfully copying -> it works fine, the problem I guess in drivers... pls help